# InputFunctionException with KeyError

Tags: snakemake

Suppose I have a code in python that generates a dictionary as the result. I need to write each element of dictionary in a separate folder which later will be used by other set of rules in snakemake. 
I have written the code as following but it does not work!

```
simulation_index_dict={1:'test1',2:'test2'}


def indexer(wildcards):
    return(simulation_index_dict[wildcards.simulation_index])

rule SimulateAll:
       input:
        expand("{simulation_index}/ProteinCodingGene/alfsim.drw",simulation_index=simulation_index_dict.keys())



rule simulate_phylogeny:
    output:
        ProteinCodingGeneParams=expand("{{simulation_index}}/ProteinCodingGene/alfsim.drw"),
        IntergenicRegionParams=expand("{{simulation_index}}/IntergenicRegions/dawg_IR.dawg"),
        RNAGeneParams=expand("{{simulation_index}}/IntergenicRegions/dawg_RG.dawg"),
        RepeatRegionParams=expand("{{simulation_index}}/IntergenicRegions/dawg_RR.dawg"),
    params:
        value= indexer,
    shell:
        """
        echo {params.value} > {output.ProteinCodingGeneParams}
        echo {params.value} > {output.IntergenicRegionParams}
        echo {params.value} > {output.RNAGeneParams}
        echo {params.value} > {output.RepeatRegionParams}
        """
```

The error it return is :

```
InputFunctionException in line 14 of /$/test.snake:
KeyError: '1'
Wildcards:
simulation_index=1
```

It seems that problems is with the params section of the rule because deleting it will eliminates the error but I can not figure out what is wrong with the params!

Comment: What happens if you use strings instead of ints as keys in your `simulation_index_dict`? (Also: I suggest you avoid using parentheses with `return`: it's not a normal function, but this probably has nothing to do with your problem.)

Comment: That solves the problem.Thanks. (And since I started using Python 3, it seems just safer to put things in Parantheses, returns less error)

Comment: In python 3, you still do not need to put parentheses for `return`. It's for `print` that you need. Regarding the strings vs ints thing, I'm guessing the reason is that wildcards are automatically converted as strings.

Comment: Note to myself: I got an `InputFunctionException` for a rule that had a function in the `input` section. I wasted a lot of time trying to debug this, and finally searched for this error on the internet and got here. Re-reading this post made me realize that the error was actually in the `params` section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The solution: using strings as dictionary keys

One can guess from the error message (`KeyError: '1'`) that some query in a dictionary went wrong on a key that is `'1'`, which happens to be a string.

However, the dictionary used in the `indexer` "params" function has integers as keys.

Apparently, using strings instead of ints as keys to this `simulation_index_dict` dictionary solves the problem (see comments below the question).

#### The cause: loss of type information during workflow inference

The cause of the problem is likely that the integer nature (inherited from `simulation_index_dict.keys()`) of the value assigned to the `simulation_index` parameter of the `expand` in `SimulateAll` is "forgotten" in subsequent steps of the workflow inference.

Indeed, the `expand` results in a list of strings, which are then matched against the output of the other rules (which also consist in strings), to infer the values of the `wildcards` attributes (which are also strings). Therefore, when the `indexer` function is executed, `wildcards.simulation_index` is a string, and this causes a KeyError when looking it up in `simulation_index_dict`.